# C# EntityFramework recursive generic model referencing

Tags: c#, entity-framework, recursion, recursive-datastructures

As an introduction I'd like to give you the following **example**:

Imagine you have different flavors, e,g, `Strawberry`, `Raspberry`, ... They are 'pure' by themself.

Now you'd like to make a flavor which by itself is a compound of other flavors, e.g. `Fruity` which consists of the two flavors `Strawberry` and `Raspberry`, each weighted 50%.

Now let's say you want to make a fresher version by adding some `Mint` to it for hot summer days. You create a flavor `Fresh n' Fruity` which consists of the two flavors `Fruity` and `Mint`, weighted 80% and 20% respectivly.

This concept of recursive referencing is what I'm trying to accomplish with a the CodeFirst approach on the EntityFramework 6.1.3.

---

In my understanding, the **database schema** should look somewhat like this:[image: UML Database Schema]

---

Trying to represent this **in code** I came up with the following construct:

```
public class Flavor
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 FlavorId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MinLength(3)]
    [MaxLength(64)]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PartFlavor> Parts { get; set; }
}
```

which references a collection of `PartFlavors` which is a derived class from a generic class called `Part`. They look like this

```
public abstract class Part<T>
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 PartId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Double Weight { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual T Component { get; set; }
}

public class PartFlavor : Part<Flavor> { }
```

the reason for deriving the part class is because the Entity Framework cannot handle generic classes and I have multiple different classes which have this kind of part mechanism.

---

My problem is that this code is not mapped in the database in the way I'd like it to be. To be exact, there is no cross-reference table generated.

Any advice?

Comment: What do you need PartFlavor-Flavor for?

Comment: @RomanoZumbé to track which PartFlavor is part of which Flavor. e.g. I have the Flavor `Strawberry`, I have an entry in PartFlavor with a reference to it and a weight of `0.5` (50%). .. maybe there are other flavors which reference this specific PartFlavor. that is what the cross table is for

Comment: I think your design of the problems solution is not the best. I would recommed to only use two tables, one that holds the pure flavors and a second one that holds mixes of them. The second table should have a flavor1Id and a flavor2id and weights for each of them.

Comment: @RomanoZumbé .. what if you want to combine more than 2 flavors?

Comment: Design the second table in a way, that you can not only put a reference to a base flavor but also to a Flavor mix (a self reference)

Comment: @RomanoZumbé what do you mean with "second table"? also, there is no difference between a base flavor and a mixed flavor, only that the one has no referenced parts and the other has (basically a mixed flavor is a summary of all its parts). i doubt that the design is the problem, I assume i missed some kind of reference property or maybe an attribute like an `[InverseProperty(..)]`. Trying to suggest a completly different layout isn't what I was asking for, but I still appreciate your effort...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after some more testing and new thoughts I came up with this:

The model `Flavor` has now these properties defined:

```
    [InverseProperty("Component")]
    public virtual ICollection<PartFlavor> Parts { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("PartOf")]
    public virtual ICollection<PartFlavor> Variants { get; set; }
```

and in the `Part` class

```
    [Required]
    [InverseProperty("Parts")]
    public virtual T Component { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Variants")]
    public virtual ICollection<T> PartOf { get; set; }
```

This generates the database like shown in the question

I hope this helps someone